# Jquery variable of nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I index to nth child of a specific jquery object.Like that...

```
var $parent = $('#slect');
var $index = 4;
var $active = $parent.children().nth-child($index);
```

I tried this but doesn't work. How can I index from Jquery Object with dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are only targeting single selectct element, you can use **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** selector to target children element based on index:

```
 var $active= $parent.children().eq($index);
```

***Note that the eq selector index is zero-based***

Answer (score 2):

You can use string concatenation

```
var $parent = $('#slect');
var $index = 4;
var $active = $parent.children(':nth-child('+$index+')');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
var $parent = $('#slect');
var $index = 4;
```

if you want to child element 4, so use below script code

```
var $active = $parent.children().eq($index-1);
```

in this code "`$index-1`" using because in "`$parent.children()`" get result in array so if you use `$index` so it get 5 element so you should use "`$index-1`".